# How to get a storage change of a transaction with geth like tenderly?

Tags: go-ethereum, state-transition

In Tenderly there is a state change section. How can I get this info with my geth node?

Comment: Can you elaborate your question please?

Comment: like in tinderly there is a section called state change which shows you which storages were changed from xxx to xxx, I want to achieve this in geth. In Parity traces they have stateDiff which would probably get what I want.